# Two jquery scripts to sum form input

Tags: jquery, sum, conflict

I am building some widgets that allow users to select radio buttons and jquery then calculates the total due.  Currently, the jquery calculations are getting mixed up since they are on the same page.  I tried changing #ids and such, but its still not working. Here is what I have so far:

Widget 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function recalculate() {
        var sum = 0;

        $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
            sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
        });

        $("#output").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }

    $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
        $('#invoice_description').val($(this).attr('rel'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Sample of my form

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-row-title"><input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="register" value="<?php echo $vendor; ?>" checked /></div>
    <div class="form-row-label">Vendor Registration (Up To 3 Attendees:  $<?php echo $vendor; ?>)</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-row-title" style="color: #090; font-weight: 700;">Total Due:</div>
    <div class="form-row-content" style="padding: 10px 0;"><b><span id="output">0.00</span></b></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Widget 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function recalculate() {
        var sum = 0;

        $(".dues input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
            sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
        });

        $("#output2").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }

    $(".dues input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
        $('#dues_description').val($(this).attr('rel'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Sample of widget 2 form

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-row-title">
    <input type="radio" id="general" class="dues" name="membership" value="<?php echo $general; ?>" rel="General Society Membership" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row-label">General Society Membership ($<?php echo $general; ?>) <i id="general-tip" class="fa fa-question-circle fa-1x"></i></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-row-title" style="color: #090; font-weight: 700;">Total Due:</div>
    <div class="form-row-content" style="padding: 10px 0;"><b><span id="output2">0.00</span></b></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: does widget1 interfere with widget2 but not the opposite way around? I'm curious because widget2 has a more specific input selector, whereas, widget1 looks for all radio inputs that are checked. So on the page, widget1 would look at any checked radio input, whereas widget2 would only look for radios checked in `.dues`. Also, widget1 attaches listeners to all radios on screen.

Comment: To avoid confusion, this isn't actually an example of a [jQuery widget](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/) and you're having this issue because of the scope of your `sum` variable. You won't run into this issue if you follow some widget examples :) and apply them to your circumstance

Comment: Didnt say i was making a jquery widget, this is a wordpress admin widget using some jquery.  the sum is only totaled in the first widget, but the 2nd widget adds to the first widget total.  If that makes sense.  I just tried adding a more specific input selector to widget 1 as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally got this figured out.  It was a bit tricky since I have other scripts also running but this is what worked for me.

```
function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;

    $(".mtg:checked").each(function () {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
    });

    $("#output").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

I changed the listener to be the input class instead of input type.  That way I was able to set different classes and not have a conflict.